# Set locale globally moment

Tags: reactjs, locale

I want to set the locale globally with moment. I use the rc-calendar, and the reason why I want to change locale is that I want to change the english month and weekday names to norwegian names. I have tried to import nb locale at the top of my file:

```
import 'moment/locale/nb';
```

and then added this in componentWillMount()

```
moment.locale('nb');
```

And the moment.locale() still returns 'en'. I have also tried to do this in the main .js file, the one with the ReactDOM.render(), without luck.

Maybe there is a better way to change the month and weekday names in rc-calendar. If so, I will be very glad for all response.

Answer (score 0):

When using `rc-calendar`, the default props is US, as seen [here](https://github.com/react-component/calendar#rc-calendar-props). I think instead of changing the locale in `moment`, change it via props, like this:

```
import nbNO from 'rc-calendar/lib/locale/nb_NO';
import 'moment/locale/nb';
<Calendar
  locale={nbNO}
  {...props}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have done this, and this works fine on all the other text, as "Back to today", "Ok", "Clear", but sadly not on the months or weekdays.